# Replacing special characters with dashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The user enters their text in `#title` and JQuery converts the string and places it in an input field named `#url`. The following code works:

```
$('#title').on('keyup', function (e) {            
   e.preventDefault();
   var str = $(this).val();
   str = str.replace(/\W+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
   $('#url').val(str);
});
```

But here is the issue, If i enter `Big "Fish" Little "Fish"` JQuery will convert this to: `big-fish-little-fish-`. So the question is how do i remove the last - at the end. Could i use something like `before()` and then it will do the replacement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing something to replace the final `-` you could also use a negative lookahead to avoid replacing anything that occurs at the end of the string and then use a subsequent statement to replace any non word char that occurs at the end with an empty space.

```
$('#title').on('keyup', function (e) {   
   //alert("key up");
   e.preventDefault();
   var str = $(this).val();
   str = str.replace(/\W+(?!$)/g, '-').toLowerCase();
   str = str.replace(/\W$/, '').toLowerCase();
   $('#url').val(str);
});
```

Example Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/ue1vedez/

Answer (score 2):

How about to add another `replace()` which would remove the ending dash

```
str = str.replace(/\W+/g, '-').replace(/\-$/, '').toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#title').on('keyup', function (e) {   
   //alert("key up");
   e.preventDefault();
   var str = $(this).val();
   str = str.replace(/\W+(?!$)/g, '-').toLowerCase();
   str = str.replace(/\W+$/, '').toLowerCase();
   $('#url').val(str);
});
```

Use W+ instead just W, because it so not allow put '-' in last when type various characters into last